# Pear error messages with PHP5.3.0

Tags: php, pear, wamp, wampserver

I get a LOT of errors when i Open up a newly installed PEAR package on a WAMP server. 
Here's the error messages.

What can i do?

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Config.php on line 650

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Config.php on line 697

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Config.php on line 757

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Config.php on line 786

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Config.php on line 914

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Config.php on line 1577

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Config.php on line 1607

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Config.php on line 2038

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Config.php on line 2091

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Registry.php on line 322

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Registry.php on line 1450

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Registry.php on line 1458

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Frontend.php on line 91

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Command.php on line 137

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Command.php on line 154

Deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Config.php on line 1026

Deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Config.php on line 1033

Deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\DependencyDB.php on line 554

Deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\DependencyDB.php on line 558

Deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Registry.php on line 1179

Deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Registry.php on line 1183

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\ChannelFile.php on line 199

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\ChannelFile.php on line 1504

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\ChannelFile.php on line 1516

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\ChannelFile.php on line 1524

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\ChannelFile.php on line 1527

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Common.php on line 492

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Common.php on line 511

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Common.php on line 530

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Common.php on line 574

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Common.php on line 607

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\PEAR\PEAR\Common.php on line 629
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Deprecated" means that a function or feature is no longer considered a good idea and will be removed in a future version of PHP. Since these are warnings about libraries you're using, you don't need to do anything yet except to make sure your PEAR version and packages are up to date. The libraries you use will need to be updated to make these warnings go away.

In a future version of PHP, the functions listed in your warnings will go away. You will then get fatal errors if your libraries have not been updated. Before you do another big PHP upgrade, make sure you have no deprecation warnings, or check them against the PHP upgrade docs to see if you will be impacted.

If you're getting these errors in your browser, adjust your error reporting settings. One way to do it:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```