# Fixing "Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated" in PEAR?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pear error messages with PHP5.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246546/pear-error-messages-with-php5-3-0)

I am new to php and I am following a tutorial on net. I dont have a knowledge about this PEAR thing what I know it is a library. I download xampp and pear is included in it. But I run into this error.
error says

> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 80
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 166

what I did was go into there and change this

```
function Config()
    {
        $this->container =& new Config_Container('section', 'root');
    } // end constructor
```

into this

```
function Config()
    {
        $this->container = new Config_Container('section', 'root');
    } // end constructor
```

I somehow get rid of the error but What if the change I made will made more errors in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Using the reference operator when instantiating an object was only necessary in ancient PHP versions. So this change will not introduce new errors.

However, the fact that you have to make this change means that you are working with ancient/legacy code you probably shouldn't be using at all. It's likely to use other poor programming practices and might even contain security flaws that are not being fixed.

Comment: I download the latest XAMPP version and my PHP is the latest version why depracated codes included in it?